# What is the simplest way to animate a view's position from say Y=0 to y=middle of screen?

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm having a hard time figuring out all the ways I can animate in android, and is there like a dead simple way to just animate a view within a layout to a centre position?

A simple code example demonstrating this would be nice?

Answer (score 1):

This line of code will translate your view to the `(50, 100)` point:

```
myView.animate().x(50f).y(100f);
```

It uses [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html).

To get screen's middle point coordinates you could do something like this:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int middleW = (int) metrics.widthPixels / 2;
int middleH = (int) metrics.heightPixels / 2;
```